# Where can I find a description of the ECAM system pages?

Tags: airbus-a320, ecam

I'm studying up on the display formats of the System Display (SD) in a typical ECAM. [Articles online](https://www.a320simulator.be/portfolio/ecam-system-display/) have stated that it is capable of showing 12 different system pages with different info. However, I cannot find anything that goes in-depth on explaining all the system pages. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This bot is not very smart...

Answer (score 1):

If your interest is more of an academic (i.e. non-operational) character you'll find plenty of information on that in https://www.smartcockpit.com/plane/AIRBUS/A320.html.

A general description of the ECAM philosophy is found under "Indicating and Recording". Then specifics on each system page are found at the specific system section, i.e. the section on hydraulics will feature the information in the hydraulics SD page.

If you're studying for a type rating, which I assume is not the case since you mention a "typical" ECAM, then your reference absolutely needs to be your current AFM/FCOM.

Answer (score -2):

You may wish to take a look at [www.ipadecam.co.uk](http://www.ipadecam.co.uk)  which will take you through all the screens

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of your source here. Only posting a link is less useful, especially if the link stops working.

Comment: @fooot That would be really hard in this case -- the site has an interactive graphic demo of how ECAM works.  The question is, "where can I find..." and this post provides an answer: "this site."  If the site goes away, then this stops being a good answer, but in the meantime, this answers the question directly by pointing to a very good training aid.  There simply is no option to post a few paragraphs or a couple of screenshots of the site in order to capture the value that is there.

Comment: @RalphJ This is why we don't like answers like this, even if they do ccurrently answer the question: [Your answer is in another castle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)

Comment: @Jamiec And yet, this answer helps out the OP & any others who come here w the same question. Is it better to disallow providing this sort of assistance to those who come here seeking help?

Comment: Also, it's clear that this answer is distinguishable from the "take the awesome tutorial HERE" bad example in the "other castle" post in multiple ways: site URL is visible, what's there is described in the answer, and this is exactly what ***is*** asked for in the OP. An example of most wonderful, most informative, bestest answer *ever*? Not quite. But still a valid & helpful one.

Comment: @RalphJ will this answer still be helpful when that website disappear? if not, this is not an answer.

Comment: To be fair, this isn't all THAT much worse than Joao B's answer...